# how to test rending inside a function in enzyme?

Tags: javascript, testing, components, enzyme

I have reactjs component where it's render function is like:

```
 render(){
 return (
  <ValleyContext.Consumer>
    {() => (<div>...</div>)}
  </ValleyContext.Consumer>
 )};
```

when I try to use the enzyme to test the internal of ValleyContext

```
const wrapper=shallow(<AMSRecent />, {context: {valley}});
console.log(wrapper.childAt(0));
```

and the result is:

```
[function]
```

I want to get the structure of

```
<div>...</div>
```

rather than just function. 
How should I get the internal structure of the rending?

Comment: *Call* the function? How is it going to get used in the actual component?